# 70s (?) Superman adventure in a world where everyone dresses like Superman

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, superman

Of course, I'm asking about a comic book, I think from about 1970.

In this comic Superman has an adventure in a world where everyone dresses like himself. I think I remember that it also involved a giant globe modeled as the planet Krypton. Superman was tasked to destroy this globe and he was afraid that the globe would turn into kryptonite when it was destroyed.

Comment: I have seen references on the wiki to _"Large Krypton Globe (Destroyed)"_ (for example, [here](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_308)) but I can't seem to track down when it was destroyed.

Comment: Definitely not what you're looking for, but [this Monty Python sketch](https://vimeo.com/25920756) was the first thing that popped into my mind. :-)

Comment: Ditto on the Monty Python sketch

Comment: I remember a story where Supes and Lois come to a planet where every man looks like Supes and every woman like Lois. But I don't remember any Krypton model.

Comment: @Thunderforge Bicycle Repair Man! But how?!

Answer (score 4):

This is a long shot as it only matches your description in broad strokes but could this be...

#### [*Superman Annual Vol 1* #11](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Annual_Vol_1_11) (1985)

***"In this comic Superman has an adventure in a world where everyone dresses like himself."***

Superman is placed into a vision where he sees Krypton and so sees a lot of Kryptonians that unsurprisingly dress like him. For example, see this page:

[image: Page showing Kryptonians]

***"I think I remember that it also involved a giant globe modeled as the planet Krypton."***

Superman isn't tasked to destroy the globe but we do get a very brief shot of a globe showing Krypton.

[image: Panels showing Globe of Krpton]